# Why am I getting a NullPointerException in this for loop?

Tags: java, exception, for-loop

here is my code:

```
Comic[] comix = new Comic[3];  
comix[0] = new Comic("The Amazing Spider-man","A-1","Very Fine",9240.00F);  
comix[0].setPrice((Float)quality.get(comix[0].condition));  
for(int i=0;i<comix.length;i++){  
    System.out.println("Title: " + comix[i].title);  
}
```

Why am I getting a NullPointerException when this code runs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're only setting the value of `comix[0]`, but you're fetching `comix[1]`.title and `comix[2]`.title in the loop as well, as `comix.length` is 3. The default value for each element in an array of reference types is `null`. The length is the length of the entire array, not just the "populated" elements.

You may find [`List<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (the most commonly used implementation being [`ArrayList<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) easier to work with.

Comment: The only thing that would explain how fast (and well) Jon is answering questions is if he is creating a ton of alts to ask the questions in the first place... :D

Answer (score 3):

Because you've only defined what is inside comix[0], not comix[1] or comix[2]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're only assigning the first of three objects and then displaying info about all three?

Answer (score 2):

Because your for-loop iterates 3 times, as the Array size is 3. It doesn't matter if the array is filled with 3 elements or not, it's size is 3 nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you declared an array that fits 3 instances of Comic and you only have one. So on the second iteration of your loop, comix[1] is null so comix[1].title throws NPE.

Answer (score 1):

comix[1].title and comix[2].title are null. You can't println a null string.

Answer (score 1):

You defined comix as `new Comic[3]`, so I'd expect Java to be going through the loop three times.  On the second iteration, `comix[1]`, there is no title.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get an error, if you do like this:

```
Comic[] comix = new Comic[3];      

for(int i=0; i<comix.length; i++){

    comix[i] = new Comic[i];

    comix[i] = new Comic("The Amazing Spider-man","A-1","Very Fine",9240.00F);

    comix[i].setPrice((Float)quality.get(comix[0].condition));   

    System.out.println("Title: " + comix[i].title);   
}
```